# Optimization of merging huge tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert, merge

I have a huge indexed MySQL table (~300-400 GB) that I need to append with new entries from time to time (where the new data takes ~10-20 GB). The raw file with new data may contain mistakes, that could be fixed only manually and are visible only when the processing script reach them. Also the new data should be available in the main db only after the full processing of the raw data is finished. So to not screw up the main table I decided to have the following workflow:

1. The script creates temporary table with the structure identical to the main table and fills it.
2. Once it is done and verified, the temporary table is inserted into main one:

   ```
   INSERT INTO main_table (all_fields_except_primary_key) SELECT all_fields_except_primary_key FROM new_table;
   ```

And this procedure is extremely slow, as I understand due to indexing new results.

I have read that inserting into indexed tables is very slow in general and some professionals suggest to DROP INDEX'es before insert big amount of data and then index again. But with such huge data indexing of whole table is very long (much longer than my naive INSERT INTO .. SELECT ..) and what is more important, the main table almost couldn't be used during it (without indexes SELECTS takes ages).

So I had an idea of indexing the temprory table before inserting (since it is very fast) and then do merge combining both indexes.

Is it possible somehow in MySQL?

And another question: possibly there're another workaround for my task?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB?  If so, why not insert directly into your main table via a transaction?

Comment: No, I don't use InnoDB. Is it an option for such huge tables? The transaction will contain a couple of millions of lines.

Comment: You're storing a ~400GB table with MyISAM?  Any partitioning (presumably not, given your question)?  On what filesystem are the data files stored?